# How to make sure multiple Kafka topologies have same partition assignment of all topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have an use case where we have multiple Kafka topologies defined in same application. I am running multiple instances of my application (e.g. 2 topologies running on 2 instances). Let's say 1st topology have 2 topics (t0, t1) with 2 partitions (p0, p1) to consume and 2nd topology have 2 topics (t2, t3) with 2 partitions (p0, p1) to consume and all the topics will have same key values (e.g. eventId). I could see that the partitions of both the topics of 1st & 2nd topology are getting assigned to a respective consumer.

Like for 1st toplogy t0-p0, t1-p0 is assigned to consumer-0 and t0-p1, t1-p1 is assigned to consumer-1.
Like for 2nd toplogy t2-p0, t3-p0 is assigned to consumer-1 and t2-p1, t3-p1 is assigned to consumer-0.

Now the thing which I wanted to make sure is that parition-0 of all the topics in their respective topology should always gets assigned to consumer-0. But I could see that in my use case, in 1st topology, t0-p0, t1-p0 are assigned to consumer-0, whereas in 2nd topology, t2-p0, t3-p0 are assigned to consumer-1.

Is there any way by which I can configure my application to always assign the consumer-0 for the 0th partition and consumer-1 should listen to partition-1 for all the topics on different topologies?

Comment: What consumer method are you using? subscribe or assign? Ultimately, why do you care which partition goes to which consumer?

Comment: @OneCricketeer: This matters to me because my both the topologies are materializing the data into stores, and when I query the stores from either of the topology, I could not get the result because partition-0 of other topology is with other instance.

Comment: Then you're getting the store incorrectly because all instances should be able to know about one another. [Refer docs on Interactive Queries](https://kafka.apache.org/28/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-remote-state-stores-for-the-entire-app) or [GlobalKTables](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/concepts.html#globalktable)

Answer (score 1):

There is a consumer configuration called [`partition.assignment.strategy`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_partition.assignment.strategy). There are Three options for this, `Range`, `RoundRobin` and `StickyAssignor`.

**RangeAssignor**

> The RangeAssignor is the default strategy. The aims of this strategy
> is to co-localized partitions of several topics. This is useful, for
> example, to join records from two topics which have the same number of
> partitions and the same key-partitioning logic.

**RoundRobinAssignor**

> The RoundRobinAssignor can be used to distribute available partitions
> evenly across all members. As previously, the assignor will put
> partitions and consumers in lexicographic order before assigning each
> partitions.

**StickyAssignor**

> The StickyAssignor is pretty similar to the RoundRobin except that it
> will try to minimize partition movements between two assignments, all
> while ensuring a uniform distribution.

I think in your scenario, you should go with `RangeAssignor`. It makes sure that same consumer has same partition from different topics if they have `same number of partitions`.

you can find great documentation [here](https://medium.com/streamthoughts/understanding-kafka-partition-assignment-strategies-and-how-to-write-your-own-custom-assignor-ebeda1fc06f3)

Comment: As the RangeAssignor is the default strategy, ideally I was expecting the same behavior where partition-0 of all topics will always get assigned the consumer-0 and parition-1 to consumer-1. But in my case, I could not see the same behavior.

Comment: What is the kafka client you are using? and kafka version? There can be bugs in those clients and versions

Comment: spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka - 3.1.2, which has kafka library version - 2.6.0